# How can I correct Invalid CSRF token errors when calling a rest API?

Tags: rest, powershell, csrf

I've got a script that will query a web rest service to find the ID for a specific object.  I've gotten the query working fine under Powershell for a single query, but I need to run several hundred queries.  It's really slow (And bad practice) to login for every single query.

I have the script logon to the server first and save the session.  The I run the rest query using a post operation.  First one works fine.  Second one bombs out saying:

```
Invoke-RestMethod : Invalid CSRF Token 
Invalid CSRF Token
An invalid cross-site request forgery token was detected in the request.
```

The code looks like this:

```
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString "password" -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("user", $secpasswd)

$headers = "Content-Type: text/plain","Accept: text/plain" 

#Login it the server to store the session to WebSession.
$login = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://devrhapapp01:8444" -Credential $cred -SessionVariable websesssion

#This one returns correctly.
$Results = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://devrhapapp01:8444/api/components/find" -ContentType "text/plain" -Method Post -Body "Search1" -WebSession $websesssion 
write-host $Results

#This one will give an error.
$Results = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://devrhapapp01:8444/api/components/find" -ContentType "text/plain" -Method Post -Body "Search1" -WebSession $websesssion 
write-host $Results
```

Comment: CSRF tokens are often per-request. You generally have to load the page to get the token and then submit that token back with the request I believe. Is there an api for getting a new token?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is going on, but try submitting the correct anti-forgery token:

```
$forgeryToken = ($login.InputFields | 
            Where { $_.name -eq "__RequestVerificationToken" }).value

$forgeryTokenPostData = "__RequestVerificationToken=$forgeryToken"

Invoke-WebRequest .... -Body $forgeryTokenPostData
```